# How to preserve space when using an Overlay command in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing, overlays

Into Beamer, I want to preserve the space when I replace an expression by another in a mathematics formula with the help of an Overlay command. For example, if we have in slide number 1 this formula:

```
\[
x+\mathrm{Trace}M=y.
\]
```

I want to replace the "\mathrm{Trace}M" by "z" for exmample such that in slide 2 the previous spacing still the same and we have :

```
\[
x+      z        =y.
\]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newlength\mylen
\newlength\mylena
\newlength\mylenb

\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand\bL{bL}
\newcommand\Div{Div}

\newcommand\getmaxlength[2]{%
  \settowidth\mylen{#1}%
  \settowidth\mylena{#1}%
  \settowidth\mylenb{#2}%
  \ifdim\mylenb>\mylena\relax
    \setlength\mylen{\mylenb}
  \fi%  
 }
\newcommand\Replace[2]{%
  \getmaxlength{#1}{#2}%
  \makebox[\mylen][c]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\onslide<1,2>{
\[
x+
\only<1>{\mathrm{Trace}M}
\only<2>{\Replace{$\mathrm{Trace}M$}{$y$}}
=z
\]
}

\onslide<3,4>{
\[
x+
\only<3>{\Replace{$\mathrm{Trace}M$}{$y$}}
\only<4>{\Replace{$y$}{$\mathrm{Trace}M$}}
=z
\]
}

\onslide<5->{
Comme l'application d\'eterminant est diff\'erentiable et que sa diff\'erentielle en l'identit\'e est l'application trace, alors $p.p.\, y\in\R^3,\,$: 
\[
\only<5>{\mathrm{det}(D_y\Phi(t,y))}
\only<6->{\Replace{$\mathrm{det}(D_y\Phi(t,y))$}{$|J(t,y)|$}}=1+t\,\only<5>{\mathrm{Trace}(D_yV(y))}
\only<6->{\Replace{$\mathrm{Trace}(D_yV(y))$}{$\Div_y V(y)$}}
+t\,\epsilon_1(t,y),\,\epsilon_1(t)\xrightarrow{\bL^{\infty}}0.
\]
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The main command is

```
\Replace{<text1>}{<text2>},
```

which typesets  but reserving the space used by . For expressions in math mode, the argument(s) should be enclosed in `$...$`.

Not related to the question, but please don't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX documents; use `\[...\]` instead; see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/3954).

Comment: Thank you. But, I encounter an error if I type "\Replace{some expression}{\mathbb{I}}". LaTeX Error: \mathbb allowed only in math mode. If I use the $ delimiter, all works fine...

Comment: There is another problem: if I use your command into \onslide<>, the spacing still not the same. Example:"\onslide<5->{
Comme l'application d\'eterminant est diff\'erentiable et que sa diff\'erentielle en l'identit\'e est l'application trace, alors :
$$
p.p.\, y\in\R^3,\,\only<5>{\mathrm{det}(D_y\Phi(t,y))}\only<6->{\Replace{\mathrm{det}(D_y\Phi(t,y))}{|J(t,y)|}}=1+t\,\only<5>{\mathrm{Trace}(D_yV(y))}\only<6->{\Div_y V(y)}+t\,\epsilon_1(t,y),\,\epsilon_1(t)\xrightarrow{\bL^{\infty}}0.
$$ 
}
"

Comment: @SAKLY And what are `\bL` and `\Div`? Please provide complete, auto-contained examples.

Comment: @SAKLY please see my updated answer.